# How to edit the same object in an other activity

Tags: java, android

I'm programming a slideshow in Java (Android).

I have two Activities :

- MainActivity.java
- SettingsActivity.java

In my SettingsActivity I would update the MillisSecond of my object.
This is my object 'Diapo' :

```
private int __millis = 4000;


public int getMillis() {return __millis;}

public void setMillis(Integer Millis) {
    __millis = Millis;
}
```

How to update this object on my second activity ?

The problem is I must create a new object Diapo on my 2nd activity, and when I back to my first activity the MillisSecond is not updated because I created a new object. How I can import my first object on my second activity an edit it ?

Thanks you

Comment: If you are using the same `Diapo` object across your program, you may need to consider changing it to `static` , that way you could get access it anywhere in your program.

Comment: i guess using `singleton` would help you or you can do it by starting `SettingActivity` for result and finish it with result after adding your `Diapo` object in result and receive it in your `MainActivity`'s `onActivityResult` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start the second activity for result. That way you can pass data from the first activity to the second one and depending on the result you can return them to the first.

In the MainActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, a_unique_integer_code);
```

in the SettingsActivity:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("millisSecond",millisSecond);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();
```

and in your MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == a_unique_integer_code) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            millisSecond = data.getInt("millisSecond");
        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
           //if there exists an event where the variable is not set you can do something about it here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a global Diapo class, and simply instantiate it instead of creating a new one. You create a static class, then it will effectively be a Singleton. Then you can just call the methods with Diapo.updateMillis.

Please read the comment below by C0D3LIC1OU5

Comment: Generally speaking, updating class instances via a Singleton pattern requires extra considerations as to would happen if the class instance is updated from the background thread, another process, etc. potentially causing serious concurrency issues during run-time. This is not a preferred design pattern not only on Android but in Java in general. It is considered a good practice to try and keep an object instance immutable when architecting code. @Nikos got the right idea here imo.